# whats the better way to validate syntax of true of false value in itcl?

Tags: tcl, itcl

I have this piece of code which validates syntax of the true or false value, something like 1 is true and 0 is false and if something others then error off:

```
itcl::body boolean::validateSyntax {} \
{
    if {![string equal [getData] "1"] && \
        ![string equal [getData] "0"] && \
        ![string equal [getData] "true"] && \
        ![string equal [getData] "false"]} \
    {
        errorHandle-errMsg \
            "Invalid boolean value."
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any other way we can get this done, some code logic which would check for 0 or 1 for true or false with "getData" and handle other cases as error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to live with Tcl's notion of a boolean, namely 0, false, no or off ==> false and 1, true, yes or on ==> true, then `string is boolean` will perform the test.

Answer (score 1):

One could use

```
if {[getdata] ni {0 1 true false}} ...
```

This code does exactly what the code in the question does. The `string is boolean` command in andy mango's answer is much more flexible.

Documentation:
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[ni (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Reasonable, but I'd prefer the `string is` tests.

Comment: The string is boolean test will also allow abbreviations and upper case spellings. Hard to say if that's a good thing or a bad thing without knowing exactly what set of values getData returns.

Comment: I prefer `string is boolean` too, but there's no harm in providing an alternative.